# Java connecting to DB2 Hangs

Tags: java, db2

I am trying a pilot project to query and write to a DB2 database. I have seen many examples on StackOverFlow, and the web. But for some reason my application just hangs when connecting to the database. I have tried different drivers but still getting the same results.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

public class DBManager {
public DBManager()
{ 
    try 
    {
        Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
    {
         System.out.println("Please include Classpath  Where your DB2 Driver is located");
         e.printStackTrace();
         return;
    }
    System.out.println("DB2 driver is loaded successfully");
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    ResultSet rset=null;
    boolean found=false;
    try 
    {
        System.out.println("DB2 Database Connecting...");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:db2://Hostname:8471/Databasename","user","password");
        if (conn != null)
        {
           System.out.println("DB2 Database Connected");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Db2 connection Failed ");
        }
        pstmt=conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM P6DEVCDB00.ADCP FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY");
        rset=pstmt.executeQuery();
        if(rset!=null)
        {
            while(rset.next())
            {
                found=true;
                System.out.println("ID: "+rset.getString("ADCONTID"));                  
            }
        }
        if (found ==false)
        {
            System.out.println("No Information Found");
        }
    } 
    catch (SQLException e) 
    {
        System.out.println("DB2 Database connection Failed");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }   
}
}
```

**UPDATED**
Application hangs with no Exceptions at

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(.
```

I have also tried using different port numbers, but some error with exception (they do vary) and other just hang.

Comment: Did you step through it with a debugger to find out on which line it hangs?

Comment: Do you see this "DB2 driver is loaded successfully" message in your console?

Comment: No Exceptions, and it hangs at the  `conn = DriverManager.getConnection(...` line

Comment: @silverback Yes I saw the message

Comment: How long do you leave it hanging? Try leaving it a few minutes to see if it times out.

Comment: @Qwerky Well the database server is on the same LAN, another application in C# and WinC connect within seconds. Do not understand why this is taking so long. I left it for a few minutes now, still hanging.

Comment: @Zion Did you try connecting manually using a client tool with the same connection url, username and password?

Comment: @Indoknight This my be a good idea to check. Any suggestions of a small lightweight client I can use that can accept my url? But I am sure of the user name and password being correct.

Comment: You can use http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/ or IBM provided DB2 client tool or any other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My connection String was wrong.  I needed to include the domain for our server.
`"jdbc:db2://Hostname/Databasename"` needed to be `"jdbc:db2://Hostname.domain/Databasename"`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your program, you need to close connection resources.

```
catch (SQLException e) 
{
    System.out.println("DB2 Database connection Failed");
    e.printStackTrace();
    try{
       rset.close();
       pstmt.close();
       conn.close();
     }catch(SQLException e2){
        System.err.println("Unable to close database resources");
        e2.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

Also, you don't need 'return' in catch statement. Catch block is used for unexcepted flow of program and it is not a good practice to again use abrupt discontinuation of code within catch using 'return'.

Comment: I can not see how this will help?

Comment: Failing to close resources hang applications sometimes. I am not sure in what environment you are running your code. This should be the case usually in multithreaded production systems.

Comment: Well the idea is later on to use this as part as a Java Web Services. So its a good idea for then, but know its just an Java application running in Eclipse, on a windows PC.